# Linq syntax for encapsulated value in array

Tags: .net, sql, vb.net, linq

I am looking for any LINQ Syntax to get the result of a frequency range of my database.

SimpleSet contains an array of frequencySets. In each FrequencySet it can be several Frequencyies. If one frequency matches to the Minimum and Maximum (1000 < 2000) it can stay in the result list.

The current code:

```vb
    Dim ret As New ObservableCollection(Of fSimpleItemSet)'the result

    Dim FreqMin As Double = 1000
    Dim FreqMax As Double = 2000
    Dim retTmp As New ObservableCollection(Of fSimpleItemSet)' fSimpleSet is the data collection
    retTmp = (From fSimple As fSimpleItemSet In Data Select fSimple) 'Get ALL items

    For Each fSimple As fSimpleItemSet In retTmp
        If fSimple.fFrequencySet IsNot Nothing Then
            For Each fFrequency As fFrequencySet In fSimple.fFrequencySet
                If fFrequency.Frequency > FreqMin And fFrequency.Frequency < FreqMax Then
                    ret.Add(fSimple)
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next
        End If
    Next
```

[image: Database structure]

Comment: Linq-to-sql/entites? That determines how you can load the frequencies.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Any` method to find elements, where at least one child passes specified condition:

```
Dim query = retTmp.Where(Function(fSimple) Not fSimple.fFrequencySet Is Nothing)
                  .Where(Function(fSimple) fSimple.fFrequencySet.Any(Function(fFrequency) fFrequency.Frequency > FreqMin And fFrequency.Frequency < FreqMax))

Dim retTmp As New ObservableCollection(Of fSimpleItemSet)(query)
```

Or in one `Where` call:

```
Dim query = retTmp.Where(Function(fSimple) Not fSimple.fFrequencySet Is Nothing AndAlso fSimple.fFrequencySet.Any(Function(fFrequency) fFrequency.Frequency > FreqMin And fFrequency.Frequency < FreqMax))
```